# Creating white space in Python so text look aligned

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
names = ['William T. Riker', 'Jean-Luc Picard', 'Worf', 'Deanna Troi']

function ='The Team'

for name in names:
    print(name,":", function)
```

This produces the following output:

```
William T. Riker : The Team
Jean-Luc Picard : The Team
Worf : The Team
Deanna Troi : The Team
```

The project which I am coding will produce a lot of lines but its a little disorienting when different names will align text differently; As in the example above. How can I make the print statement so that it looks like the example below?

```
William T. Riker : The Team
Jean-Luc Picard  : The Team
Worf             : The Team
Deanna Troi      : The Team
```

I already know the maximum length of character in name variable. How can i create white space so the text will always align in a manner as outlined in the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this small change to find max length first

```
max_len = max(len(x) for x in names)

for name in names:
    print(name.ljust(max_len),":", function)
```

Comment: Thanks, for your help. This is even better way then I was asking for with static white space!